# How to solve MySQL installation on Mac

Tags: mysql, installation

[[image]

I am having an error with installing MySQL. It keeps running I am unable to go to the next step.

I deleted it several times and re-installed it and still I keep getting the same issue. Please help.

Comment: I don't think this question is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for StackOverflow. You'd probably have better luck asking on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Agree.  If you have an M1 Mac you might want to make sure you have a compatible package, and you might want to consider using HomeBrew or even Docker.  Docker is a nice way to have the package while still keeping your Mac OS relatively 'clean'.